# UI Controls for Java

Tags: java, user-interface, controls

I'm looking for UI Controls for Java Applications. Just like how there are so many libraries for .Net, like Telerik, DevExpress, Infragistics, etc.

Are there similar libraries for Java Applications?

Thanks!

Comment: Telerik now seems to have a Java offering: http://www.telerik.com/jsp-ui

Answer (score 6):

go for

1. [Qt Jambi](http://qt-jambi.org/)
2. [jgoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/)
3. SwingX
4. [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/)
5. [NetBeans Platform](http://platform.netbeans.org/)
6. [Eclipse Rich Client Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/community/rcp.php)

Answer (score 3):

This was recommended to me by a good friend from Zappos.com :: http://www.zkoss.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends in the IDE you are using.  WebLogic has custom controls (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13196_01/platform/docs81/isv/controls.html) as well as instructions on how to create your own custom controls.